# wpf need grid with 3 rows to fill window and only have middle row stretch

Tags: wpf, grid, window, fill, stretch

Here's my code (which isn't working btw):

```
<DockPanel MinWidth="776" Margin="13" LastChildFill="True" Height="522" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top" MinWidth="200">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="70" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="150" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
</Grid>
...
</DockPanel>
```

When I vertically size the control everything just sticks to the top (which I want, except for the middle to stretch).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you can just stick to dock panels, you do something like the following:

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="true">
    <DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="70" />
    <DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Height="150" />
    <DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top"><!-- Expandable content here--></DockPanel>
</DockPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to remove some values from the dock panel `LastChildFill="True", Height="522" VerticalAlignment="Top"` are stopping the grid from sizing.

Try this:

```
<DockPanel MinWidth="776" >
        <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top" MinWidth="200">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="70" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="150" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Rectangle Fill="Blue" Grid.Row="0" />
            <Rectangle Fill="Green" Grid.Row="1" />
            <Rectangle Fill="Red" Grid.Row="2" />
        </Grid>
    </DockPanel>
```